# Member verification vs Interface

Tags: c#, ruby, dynamic, interface, duck-typing

I was ready up on Ruby's method of enforcing interfaces w/ dynamic typing by checking for the existence of methods/properties that satisfy an interface.

In what ways is this overall just a better design principle than using interfaces? What are the pros/cons. For example you could implement the same concept in C# but I'm not sure if it would have the same value,

```
public class Foo
{
   public Foo(dynamic _obj)
   {
        MethodInfo[] methods= _obj.GetType().GetMethods();

        if (!methods.Any(x => x.Name == "SomeRequiredMethod")
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Object does not meet interface requirements.");
        }
   }

   // proceed with functionality that requires the method
}
```

And of course you could extend this to check more than just the name, like the signature, return type, etc.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several major issues problems with this approach:

1. reflection is slow
2. dynamic calls are also much slower than strongly-typed calls
3. the code is more complicated

And I can't see any advantage, except perhaps for very specific needs...

C# was designed as a static, strongly-typed language, and even though it now has some dynamic capabilities, they should only be used when there is no strongly-typed alternative.

If you really need to use the object dynamically, don't check the members manually: instead, put the code in a try block, and catch the `RuntimeBinderException` that will occur if a member you call is missing.

Comment: What about in Ruby though, do you know if there is a performance hit? I clocked it at 39ms, which I suppose could definitely add up.

Comment: I don't know much about Ruby, but its a dynamic language, so it's certainly more suitable for this kind of thing. The timing you give isn't a very useful information without context... I don't know what your method does, and how you did your test.